# visit child actions of an action sequence in cocos 2d with lua

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I have an action sequence like this:

```
cc.Sequence:create(move_ease_in, cc.CallFunc:create(calls1), move_ease_in_back, cc.CallFunc:create(calls2))
```

I want to copy the actions to another sprite, but remove all the CallFunc actions. So I need to parse the action and visit every node in the action tree to remove the specific action.

I know I can just do it like:

```
anotherSprite:runAction(cc.Sequence:create(move_ease_in, move_ease_in_back))
```

but the actual actions in my program are much more complicated and there are too many actions, so I must do it without hard coding the whole action once more.

In other words, is there any way to visit all the child action of an action and get the type of each action in lua?

I'm using cocos 2d 3.0 + lua 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access child actions of `cc.Sequence`. In its C++ implementation, a `Sequence` only contains 2 child actions. If you create a `Sequence` with 3 child actions, the sequence will look like: `Sequence(action1, Sequence(action2, action3))`

So, if you really need to access the child actions, you can extend `cc.Sequence`, and save child actions in the extended class, so that you can access them.